# Pandas: add a column to a multiindex column dataframe

Tags: pandas, multi-index

I would like to add a column to the second level of a multiindex column dataframe.

```
In [151]: df
Out[151]: 
first        bar                 baz           
second       one       two       one       two 
A       0.487880 -0.487661 -1.030176  0.100813 
B       0.267913  1.918923  0.132791  0.178503
C       1.550526 -0.312235 -1.177689 -0.081596
```

The usual trick of direct assignment does not work:

```
In [152]: df['bar']['three'] = [0, 1, 2]

In [153]: df
Out[153]: 
first        bar                 baz           
second       one       two       one       two 
A       0.487880 -0.487661 -1.030176  0.100813
B       0.267913  1.918923  0.132791  0.178503
C       1.550526 -0.312235 -1.177689 -0.081596
```

How can I add the third row to under "bar"?

Comment: I guess the OP means to add the third *column*.

Answer (score 123, accepted):

It's actually pretty simple (FWIW, I originally thought to do it your way):

```
df['bar', 'three'] = [0, 1, 2]
df = df.sort_index(axis=1)
print(df)

        bar                        baz          
        one       two  three       one       two
A -0.212901  0.503615      0 -1.660945  0.446778
B -0.803926 -0.417570      1 -0.336827  0.989343
C  3.400885 -0.214245      2  0.895745  1.011671
```

Comment: Thanks. I must say it is totally not obvious (to me) why the new column shows up only after using sort_index.

Comment: Oh sorry that's not part of the answer, just me being picky. It will actually show up as soon as you call `df['bar', 'three'] = [0, 1, 2]`. By default pandas will put it at the end of the DataFrame (after [baz, two]). I just wanted to see it with the other `bar`s.

Comment: This appends the new column 'three' to the subtable 'bar'. But what if you want to insert (instead of append) this new column in subtable 'bar', e.g. insert 'three' in between 'one' and 'two'?

Comment: The order of columns doesn't really matter here. If you wanted to reorder them so they displayed "one, three, two" you could do that by using `df.loc[:, XX]` where `XX` has tuples ("bar", "one"), ("bar", "three"), etc.

Comment: Doesn't work for me in my similar case; I'm getting `TypeError: cannot insert an item into a CategoricalIndex that is not already an existing category`. I don't know what might make a multiindex a `CategorialIndex` as opposed to a "regular" one.

Comment: Is it possible to generalize this to adding a third column to every sub-index? (i.e. in this case to have the `three` column added both for `bar` and for `baz`?

Comment: @JorisKinable I posted the solution for using `insert` in a separate answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75791460/6383205

Answer (score 27):

If we want to add a multi-level column:

Source DF:

```
In [221]: df
Out[221]:
first        bar                 baz
second       one       two       one       two
A      -1.089798  2.053026  0.470218  1.440740
B       0.488875  0.428836  1.413451 -0.683677
C      -0.243064 -0.069446 -0.911166  0.478370
```

**Option 1**: adding result of division: `bar / baz` as a new `foo` column

```
In [222]: df = df.join(
     ...:     df[['bar']].div(df['baz']).rename(columns={'bar':'foo'}))

In [223]: df
Out[223]:
first        bar                 baz                 foo
second       one       two       one       two       one       two
A      -1.089798  2.053026  0.470218  1.440740 -2.317647  1.424980
B       0.488875  0.428836  1.413451 -0.683677  0.345873 -0.627250
C      -0.243064 -0.069446 -0.911166  0.478370  0.266761 -0.145172
```

**Option 2**: adding multi-level column with three "sub-columns":

```
In [235]: df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(
     ...:     np.random.rand(3,3),
     ...:     columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['new'], ['one','two','three']]),
     ...:     index=df.index))

In [236]: df
Out[236]:
first        bar                 baz                 new
second       one       two       one       two       one       two     three
A      -1.089798  2.053026  0.470218  1.440740  0.274291  0.636257  0.091048
B       0.488875  0.428836  1.413451 -0.683677  0.668157  0.456931  0.227568
C      -0.243064 -0.069446 -0.911166  0.478370  0.333824  0.363060  0.949672
```

Comment: And how to appen and independiente column? I tried with:
`df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(3, 1),
                                 columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['new']]),
                                 index = df.index))` 
Is the right way?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to add multiple columns to a multiindex column dataframe, you can try

1. All same value for columns

```
df[[("foo", "bar1"), ("foo", "bar2")]] = 2
```

```
        bar                 baz            foo
        one       two       one       two bar1 bar2
0  0.487880 -0.487661 -1.030176  0.100813    2    2
1  0.267913  1.918923  0.132791  0.178503    2    2
2  1.550526 -0.312235 -1.177689 -0.081596    2    2
```

2. Same value for each column

```py
df[[("foo", "bar1"), ("foo", "bar2")]] = [2, 3]
```

```
        bar                 baz            foo
        one       two       one       two bar1 bar2
0  0.487880 -0.487661 -1.030176  0.100813    2    3
1  0.267913  1.918923  0.132791  0.178503    2    3
2  1.550526 -0.312235 -1.177689 -0.081596    2    3
```

3. Different value for each cell

```py
df[[("foo", "bar1"), ("foo", "bar2")]] = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]] # shape is (3, 2) where 3 is index length and 2 is new added column length
```

```
        bar                 baz            foo
        one       two       one       two bar1 bar2
0  0.487880 -0.487661 -1.030176  0.100813    1    2
1  0.267913  1.918923  0.132791  0.178503    3    4
2  1.550526 -0.312235 -1.177689 -0.081596    5    6
```

---

Another usecase is that we have a single index dataframe, and we want to concat it to the multi index dataframe

```py
        bar                 baz
       one       two       one       two     concat to      bar1  bar2
0  0.487880 -0.487661 -1.030176  0.100813   <---------  0     1     2
1  0.267913  1.918923  0.132791  0.178503               1     3     4
2  1.550526 -0.312235 -1.177689 -0.081596               2     5     6
```

1. Generate a list of tuples for columns

```py
df[[("foo", col) for col in single_index_df.columns]] = single_index_df
```

```
        bar                 baz            foo
        one       two       one       two bar1 bar2
0  0.487880 -0.487661 -1.030176  0.100813    1    2
1  0.267913  1.918923  0.132791  0.178503    3    4
2  1.550526 -0.312235 -1.177689 -0.081596    5    6
```

2. Create a new multi index columns dataframe from the single index dataframe as **Option 2** of *MaxU - stop genocide of UA*

```
df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(single_index_df.values,
                          columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['foo'], single_index_df.columns]),
                          index=single_index_df.index))
```

3. Create a multi index dataframe from single index dataframe with `pd.concat({'foo': single_index_df}, axis=1)`

```py
df = pd.concat([df, pd.concat({'foo': single_index_df}, axis=1)], axis=1)
```

Comment: These are nice solutions.  I like the first one because it won't create duplicates if accidentally executed more than once (as can happen when using notebooks for example).  The last one does.  Not sure about 2.

Comment: Actually, I just implemented method 1 on a large data frame and got the following repeated warning: "PerformanceWarning: DataFrame is highly fragmented.  This is usually the result of calling `frame.insert` many times, which has poor performance.  Consider joining all columns at once using pd.concat(axis=1) instead. To get a de-fragmented frame, use `newframe = frame.copy()`"

Comment: @Bill Sorry for the late reply, I remember I have noticed your comment, but busy with my work and forgot to reply. I'm not really sure which method you refer when saying **method 1**, I have two method 1 in different usecases. I'm not really sure what fragment is, but from the warning message, I think for both usecases, the last method which begins with 'Create a multi index dataframe from single index dataframe' is possible a right way to solve the warning.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to `insert` (instead of append at the end of the DF) do this:

```py
df.insert(0, ('bar', 'three'), [0, 1, 2])
```

The second item has to be hashable, so a list will not work.