# How split a column in two columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have el next dataframe

```
data=read_csv('enero.csv')
data

           Fecha           DirViento  MagViento  
0   2011/07/01  00:00        318        6.6      
1   2011/07/01  00:15        342        5.5        
2   2011/07/01  00:30        329        6.6        
3   2011/07/01  00:45        279        7.5        
4   2011/07/01  01:00        318        6.0        
5   2011/07/01  01:15        329        7.1        
6   2011/07/01  01:30        300        4.7        
7   2011/07/01  01:45        291        3.1
```

How to split the column Fecha in two columns,for example, get a dataframe as follows:

```
      Fecha     Hora     DirViento  MagViento  
0   2011/07/01  00:00        318        6.6      
1   2011/07/01  00:15        342        5.5        
2   2011/07/01  00:30        329        6.6        
3   2011/07/01  00:45        279        7.5        
4   2011/07/01  01:00        318        6.0        
5   2011/07/01  01:15        329        7.1        
6   2011/07/01  01:30        300        4.7        
7   2011/07/01  01:45        291        3.1
```

I am using pandas for to read data

I try to calculate daily averages from a monthly database has daily data recorded every 15 minutes. To do this, use pandas and grouped the columns: Date and Time for get a dataframe as follow:

```
 Fecha Hora
 2011/07/01 00:00 -4.4
            00:15 -1.7
            00:30 -3.4
 2011/07/02 00:00 -4.5
            00:15 -4.2
            00:30 -7.6
 2011/07/03 00:00 -6.3
            00:15 -13.7
            00:30 -0.3
```

with this look, I get the following

```
grouped.mean()                                                                         

Fecha     DirRes
2011/07/01 -3 
2011/07/02 -5
2011/07/03 -6
```

Comment: That didn't answer my question.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to have Fecha as an actual datetime object, e.g. passing parse_dates=['Fecha'] to read_csv.

Comment: I agree with @AndyHayden you can pass to `read_csv` a `parse_dates` parameter and this will read the string and try to parse it as a datetime like so: `data=read_csv('enero.csv', parse_dates=['Fecha'])`

Answer (score 5):

Here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16088741/pandas-add-a-column-to-a-multiindex-column-dataframe) to the quite similar question that has been answered before, hope it is helpful. In your case, you can split the content in the Fecha by the space and construct a list of the second part of the string. Then add the content to the new column inserted

```
import pandas as p
t = p.read_csv('test2.csv')

#store into a data frame
df = p.DataFrame(t)


#update the fecha col value and create new col hora
lista = [item.split(' ')[2] for item in df['Fecha']]
listb = p.Series([item.split(' ')[0] for item in df['Fecha']])
df['Fecha'].update(listb)
df['Hora'] = lista

#change Hora position
#I am not sure whether this is efficient or not
#as I am also quite new to Pandas
col = df.columns.tolist()
col = col[-1:]+col[:-1]
col[0], col[1] = col[1], col[0]

df = df[col]

print df
```

Hope this could solve your problem and here is the output.

```
        Fecha   Hora  DirViento  MagViento
0  2011/07/01  00:00        318        6.6
1  2011/07/01  00:15        342        5.5
2  2011/07/01  00:30        329        6.6
3  2011/07/01  00:45        279        7.5
4  2011/07/01  01:00        318        6.0
5  2011/07/01  01:15        329        7.1
6  2011/07/01  01:30        300        4.7
7  2011/07/01  01:45        291        3.1
```