# Add calculated column to a pandas pivot table

Tags: python, pandas

I have created a pandas data frame and then converted it into pivot table.

My pivot table looks like this:

```
Operators   TotalCB     Qd(cb)  Autopass(cb)
Aircel India    55        11       44
Airtel Ghana    20        17        3
Airtel India    41         9        9
Airtel Kenya    9          4        5
Airtel Nigeria  24        17        7
AT&T USA        18        10        8
```

I was wondering how to add calculated columns so that I get my pivot table with Autopass% (`Autopass(cb)/TotalCB*100`) just like we are able to create them in Excel using calculated field option.

I want my pivot table output to be something like below:

```
Operators   TotalCB     Qd(cb)  Autopass(cb)    Qd(cb)% Autopass(cb)%
Aircel India    55          11    44             20%     80%
Airtel Ghana    20          17     3             85%     15%
Airtel India    41          29     9             71%     22%
Airtel Kenya     9           4     5             44%     56%
AT&T USA        18          10     8             56%     44%
```

How do I define the function which calculates the percentage columns and how to apply that function to my two columns namely `Qd(cb)` and `Autopass(cb)` to give me additional calculated columns

Comment: Clearly some code has been written @Tony: You don't get to the stage of making a pivot table in pandas without some code. 
Your comment was not helpful.

Comment: Thanks Oxinabox. @Tony Yes I imported the data using read_csv into a dataframe and the used the pivot_table function to create the pivot table.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should do it, assuming `data` is your pivoted dataframe:

```
data['Autopass(cb)%'] = data['Autopass(cb)'] / data['TotalCB'] * 100
data['Qd(cb)%'] = data['Qd(cb)'] / data['TotalCB'] * 100
```

Adding a new column to a dataframe is as simple as `df['colname'] = new_series`. Here we assign it with your requested function, when we do it as a vector operation it creates a new series.

Comment: In my case the pivot returns a multi index for the columns, if this is so, you need to either "flatten" the header: 
    df.columns = df.columns.map('{0[0]} {0[1]}'.format)

or adress the columns like that: 

    df = df.join(df[['bar']].div(df['baz']).rename(columns={'bar':'foo'}))

(from https://stackoverflow.com/a/45189391/2360229)