# Pandas: Add calculated column to a pivot_table

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

unfortunately this 
[Add calculated column to a pandas pivot table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26313881/add-calculated-column-to-a-pandas-pivot-table) doesnt help me

My code:

`table = pd.pivot_table(df,index=['JOBFAMILIE1', 'POS_AUSPR1'],
                       columns=['GESCHL'],
                       values=['GESAMTDIREKT'],
                       aggfunc={'GESAMTDIREKT': [np.mean,np.count_nonzero]},
                       fill_value ="-")`

Resulting Table:

Jan[image: My resulting Table:]

now i need to compute the difference of mean "männlich" and "weiblich"

Comment: Why doesn't it help you? What is it that's not working etc. Also, if you provide a way for us to generate this DataFrame it would be very helpful (so we can run your code).