# How to add calculated % to a pandas pivottable

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a pivottable similiar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28613911/pandas-add-calculated-column-to-a-pivot-table), which doesn't seem to have an answer. I have a pivottable called `grouped` like this:

[image]

```
grouped = age_gender_bkts.pivot_table('population_in_thousands',index='gender',
columns='country_destination', aggfunc='sum').unstack()
```

This is taken from the pandas dataframe age_gender_bkts:

```
age_gender_bkts = pd.read_csv('airbnb/age_gender_bkts.csv')
age_gender_bkts[:10]

  age_bucket country_destination gender  population_in_thousands  year
0       100+                  AU   male                        1  2015
1      95-99                  AU   male                        9  2015
2      90-94                  AU   male                       47  2015
3      85-89                  AU   male                      118  2015
4      80-84                  AU   male                      199  2015
5      75-79                  AU   male                      298  2015
6      70-74                  AU   male                      415  2015
7      65-69                  AU   male                      574  2015
8      60-64                  AU   male                      636  2015
9      55-59                  AU   male                      714  2015
```

I am looking to get, for each country, the ratio between male and female `population_in_thousands` as a % for each gender e.g. `12024/11899+12024` for `AU`.

I am very new to pandas, numpy, looking for a generic solution to calculate columns based on `pivot_table`. Also, if the reply has a way for me to have created these groups by gender and country without using `pivot_table`, e.g. `groupby` (I couldn't figure it out), that would really help me in my learning.

Comment: Can you add to question text instead of images?

Comment: I've added that too for you.

Comment: @jezrael I don't think you strictly need that to answer the question here

Comment: Ok, maybe you can try `print grouped / grouped.groupby(level=0).transform(sum)`

Comment: Yes this works! How can I add that calculation to a new column in the original df e.g. `age_gender_bkts['prop']`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) and [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html). Last you can [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) data to original `DataFrame`:

```
print age_gender_bkts
  age_bucket country_destination gender  population_in_thousands  year
0       100+                  AU   male                        1  2015
1      95-99                  AU   male                        9  2015
2      90-94                  CA   male                       47  2015
3      85-89                  CA   male                      118  2015
4      80-84                  AU   male                      199  2015
5      75-79                  NL   male                      298  2015
6      70-74                  NL   male                      415  2015
7      65-69                  AU   male                      574  2015
8      60-64                  AU   male                      636  2015
9      55-59                  AU   male                      714  2015

grouped = age_gender_bkts.pivot_table('population_in_thousands',index='gender', columns='country_destination', aggfunc='sum').unstack()
df  = (grouped / grouped.groupby(level=0).transform(sum)).reset_index().rename(columns={0:'prop'})
print df
  country_destination gender  prop
0                  AU   male     1
1                  CA   male     1
2                  NL   male     1

print pd.merge(age_gender_bkts, df, on=['country_destination', 'gender'])
  age_bucket country_destination gender  population_in_thousands  year  prop
0       100+                  AU   male                        1  2015     1
1      95-99                  AU   male                        9  2015     1
2      80-84                  AU   male                      199  2015     1
3      65-69                  AU   male                      574  2015     1
4      60-64                  AU   male                      636  2015     1
5      55-59                  AU   male                      714  2015     1
6      90-94                  CA   male                       47  2015     1
7      85-89                  CA   male                      118  2015     1
8      75-79                  NL   male                      298  2015     1
9      70-74                  NL   male                      415  2015     1
```