# Assign multi-index column while preserving the order of index level values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following data frame with multi-index columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(6).reshape(2, 3),
    columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('foo', 'a'), ('bar', 'a'), ('bar', 'b')]))

  foo bar   
    a   a  b
0   0   1  2
1   3   4  5
```

I would like to assign a new column `('foo', 'b')` such that the order of values in index level 0 is preserved, i.e. the resulting columns should be `('foo', 'a'), ('foo', 'b'), ('bar', 'a'), ('bar', 'b')`:

```
expected = pd.DataFrame(
    [[0, 10, 1, 2], [3, 11, 4, 5]],
    columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['foo', 'bar'], list('ab')]))

      foo     bar   
    a   b   a  b
0   0  10   1  2
1   3  11   4  5
```

The following would be nice and somehow intuitive, but unfortunately `assign` doesn't accept positional arguments:

```
df.assign({('foo', 'b'): [10, 11]})
```

So I tried various options, but the new column is always appended at the end:

```
# using column indexer (appends the new column to the end):
df2 = df.copy()
df2['foo', 'b'] = [10, 11]
print(df2)  # columns out of order
print(df2.sort_index(axis=1))  # order of "foo" and "bar" swapped

# using join (appends the new column to the end):
df3 = df.join(pd.DataFrame([10, 11], index=df.index,
    columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('foo', 'b')])))
print(df3)  # columns out of order

# saving index levels beforehand doesn't help because they are sorted:
df4 = df.copy()
columns = df.columns.levels[0]  # columns out of order
df4['foo', 'b'] = [10, 11]
df4 = df4[columns]
print(df4)  # columns out of order
```

I could use `[x[0] for x in df.columns]`, then remove duplicates (without `set` because order should be preserved) and then use the result to index into the columns of the new data frame but this approach feels way too heavy for such a simple task.

I am aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16088741/3767239) however the answers there don't preserve the column ordering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I went with the following:

1. create first level column indexer
2. remove duplicates (using `dict` preserves order)
3. use it to index into the new data frame, restoring the old order

Code sample:

```
df['foo', 'b'] = [10, 11]
df = df[list(dict.fromkeys([x[0] for x in df.columns]))]
```

Answer (score 1):

That is `insert`

```
df.insert(1, ('foo', 'b'), [10, 11])
df
  foo     bar   
    a   b   a  b
0   0  10   1  2
1   3  11   4  5
```

Comment: nice 1, `.loc` disrupts the  order somehow

Comment: `insert` seems to require the absolute position along the columns, you just hard coded it, but for a more complex setup this might be unfeasible. So I need a separate function to compute that index position? Something like `next(it.dropwhile(lambda x: x[1][0] == 'foo', it.dropwhile(lambda x: x[1][0] != 'foo', enumerate(df.columns))))[0]`. Seems pretty heavy too.