# Pandas: add multiple columns to a multiindex column dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

This question is an attempt to generalise the solution provided for the this question:

[Pandas: add a column to a multiindex column dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16088741/pandas-add-a-column-to-a-multiindex-column-dataframe)

I need to produce a column for each column index.

The solution provided by `spencerlyon2` works when we want to add a single column:

`df['bar', 'three'] = [0, 1, 2]`

However I would like to generalise this operation for every first level column index.

Source DF:

```
In [1]: df
Out[2]:
first        bar                 baz
second       one       two       one       two
A      -1.089798  2.053026  0.470218  1.440740
B       0.488875  0.428836  1.413451 -0.683677
C      -0.243064 -0.069446 -0.911166  0.478370
```

Target DF below, requires that the `three` column is the addition of the `one` and `two` columns of its respective index.

```
In [1]: df
Out[2]:
first        bar                           baz                 
second       one       two     three       one       two      three
A      -1.089798  2.053026  0.963228‬  1.440740 -2.317647  -0.876907‬
B       0.488875  0.428836  0.917711 -0.683677  0.345873  -0.337804‬
C      -0.243064 -0.069446 -0.312510  0.478370  0.266761   0.745131‬
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `join` with two data frames with same indexes to create a bunch of columns all at once.

---

First, calculate the sum using `groupby` against `axis=1`

```
ndf = df.groupby(df.columns.get_level_values(0), axis=1).sum()
```

```
        bar       baz
A  0.963228  1.910958
B  0.917711  0.729774
C -0.312510 -0.432796
```

(PS: If you have more than two columns, you may do

```
df.loc[:, (slice(None), ['one', 'two'])].groupby(df.columns.get_level_values(0), axis=1).sum()
```

to slice only columns 'one' and 'two' first, and just *then* `groupby`)

Then, make it match your column indexes, i.e. make it a MultiIndexed data frame just like your original data frame

```
ndf.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([ndf.columns, ['three']])
```

```
        bar       baz
      three     three
A  0.963228  1.910958
B  0.917711  0.729774
C -0.312510 -0.432796
```

Finally, [`df.join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html)

```
finaldf = df.join(ndf).sort_index(axis=1)
```

If you really care about the ordering, use `reindex`

```
finaldf.reindex(['one', 'two', 'three'], axis=1, level=1)
```

---

```
first        bar                           baz                    
second       one       two     three       one       two     three
A      -1.089798  2.053026  0.963228  0.470218  1.440740  1.910958
B       0.488875  0.428836  0.917711  1.413451 -0.683677  0.729774
C      -0.243064 -0.069446 -0.312510 -0.911166  0.478370 -0.432796
```

Comment: Thank you rafaelc for your reply. For some reason, I was getting a ValueError `ValueError("Grouper and axis must be same length")` within Groupby when using `df.columns.get_level_values(0)`. I changed this to `level=0` and it worked. Any idea what is raising the value error?

Comment: @SO_tourist you likely forgot to add "axis=1" as an option in the groupby

Answer (score 1):

I started from your sample input:

```
first        bar                 baz          
second       one       two       one       two
A      -1.089798  2.053026  0.470218  1.440740
B       0.488875  0.428836  1.413451 -0.683677
C      -0.243064 -0.069446 -0.911166  0.478370
```

To add a new column to each level 0 of the column MultiIndex, 
you can run something like:

```
for c1 in df.columns.get_level_values('first').unique():
    # New column int index
    cInd = int(df.columns.get_loc(c1).stop)
    col = (c1, 'three')      # New column name
    newVal = df[(c1, 'one')] + df[(c1, 'two')]
    df.insert(loc=cInd, column=col, value=newVal)  # Insert the new column
```

In the above example, values in new columns are consecutive numbers, but
in your case set them as you wish.

The result of my code (after the column sort) is:

```
first        bar                           baz                    
second       one       two     three       one       two     three
A      -1.089798  2.053026  0.963228  0.470218  1.440740  1.910958
B       0.488875  0.428836  0.917711  1.413451 -0.683677  0.729774
C      -0.243064 -0.069446 -0.312510 -0.911166  0.478370 -0.432796
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I amended my question slightly as I might not have explained myself clearly. I would require a single column to be added per index, and for the sake of example, the new column is the addition of the `one` and the `two` columns

Comment: I corected my answer. Now a new column is added for each name at the top level of the column MultiIndex.

Comment: How come the result is correct? OP explicitly stated `three` should be the sum of `one` and `two` haha ;p

Comment: You are right, initially I missed this detail. Now the new column contains the sum.

Comment: Now looks correct! But even though this works, it will be very very very slow ;/