# Assigning total and average to deeply nested columns pandas multi index

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a bizarre mutliindex such as follows:

```
test_df = {}
for letter in ['A', "B"]:
  for number in range(2, 4):
    for other_number in range(number):
      for id_ in range(100, 105):

        test_df[(letter,  number, other_number,  "int", id_)] = np.random.randint(10)
        test_df[(letter, number,  other_number, "float", id_)] = np.random.random(1)
# note: there is prob a better way of doing this, but it works
test_df = pd.DataFrame(test_df).stack().loc[0]
```

[image]

I would like to add the total and average at the `other_number` level.
For example, for total I can easily compute

```
totals = test_df.loc[:, (slice(None), slice(None), slice(None), 'int')].sum(axis=1, level=[0, 1])
```

i.e.

```
        A   B
    2   3   2   3
100 7   16  5   15
101 10  13  15  11
102 4   10  16  16
103 4   14  11  14
104 13  22  4   7
```

but the assignment is giving me problem.

```
test_df.loc[:, (slice(None), slice(None), slice(None), 'total')] = totals
```

specifically

```
KeyError: 'total'
```

I understand that `total` was not in my keys, but this is the whole point: I want to create a new column.
So my questions are:

- how do I assign to the total?
- how do I assign the average of the float (at the same level?)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16088741/pandas-add-a-column-to-a-multiindex-column-dataframe

Comment: thanks! I think it's a little different because I am trying to assign to a whole data frame and not a singe list