# add columns to specific level pivot tables in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I am trying to achieve this multi-indexing form with a pandas pivot table.
[image]

since the original data were like this.

[image]

I used this code `table = pd.pivot_table(df, index=str(df.columns[0]), columns =list(df.columns[1:4]), values='Value')` to get this result

[image]

but now I need to add these three columns (Forcast, Tolerance, Baseline Forcast) to the most detailed level of the pivot table for each subproduct like adding them under the ECo, I tried this  `table[('OcP', 'CoC', 'tolerance')] = 0` it worked but added the column to the end of the pivot table like this.

[image]

so how can add them and make them fall under the same sub-category that is already existed not at the end of the pivot like shown above?
Note: I know there are similar questions but they didn't solve my case.

Comment: Your call ('OcP', 'CoC', 'tolerance') means level1, level2, level3.  If you do df["OcP"] = 0 it will create a column with OcP on level1 of MultiIndex.

Comment: Can you specify more about where you want these values to be in the index hierarchy?

Comment: yes i mean the levels, but i want to insert the new columns to level3,

Comment: I want to add them at level3 so they are similar to (B, ENS, or G)

Comment: Ok, but you need need to specify the higher levels as well.

Comment: I did  specify the higher two levels by that  table[('OcP', 'CoC', 'tolerance')] = 0 since the 'OcP' and 'CoC' already exist and the new part is 'tolerance', instead of adding it he created a new two higher levels with same names and added the 'tolerance' column to them at the end of the table like shown at the last image

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239067/discussion-between-bido-boy-and-borut-flis).

Comment: Than I think you script already works. True it looks like it is added at the end, but if you call "Ocp" you will see "tolerance" is added to the hierarchy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
table[('OcP', 'CoC', 'tolerance')] = 0
```

Sets 'OcP' as level1 'CoC' as level2 and 'tolerance' as level3.

You said you want them on level3 than you have to set them like this:

```
table[(level1, level2, "CoC")]
```

You need to specify the index up in the hierarchy as well.

The new column is than added to the end of the data-frame and it appears as if it is not part of the multi-index hierarchy, but it is, you can check this by calling table[(level1, level2)] you will see it is included.

If you want to display them ordered by the multi-index hierarchy you should sort the columns:

```
df.iloc[:,df.columns.sortlevel(level=[0,1])[1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally achieved the solution thanks to [borut](https://stackoverflow.com/users/847773/borut-flis) he lighted the way to it and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16088741/pandas-add-a-column-to-a-multiindex-column-dataframe) , it was using `table[('OcP', 'CoC', 'tolerance')] = 0` and then apply  `pivot.sort_index(axis=1)` to the pivot.

Comment: I made an edit to the answer, can you accept it?